# Allow remote connection to this computer using WinAPI

Tags: winapi

I need to set `Allow remote connections to this computer` on, so I want to know If I can enable it by using WinAPI.

[image]

Does anyone know If this can be done with any function?

Comment: This is a sysadmin task. Do it with group policy.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to know If I could do that by using the Windows API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you need set next registry keys:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\fDenyTSConnections = 0 
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\UserAuthentication = (IsDlgButtonChecked() == BST_CHECKED)
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\SecurityLayer = 0 or 1 or 2
```

if radio-button not selected you need set only

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\fDenyTSConnections = 1
```

also you need enable [`"@FirewallAPI.dll,-28752"`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749376(WS.10).aspx) Firewall group by next code:

```
HRESULT EnableFirewallRule(PCWSTR cgroup, VARIANT_BOOL enable)
{
    if (BSTR group = SysAllocString(cgroup))
    {
        INetFwPolicy2* pNetFwPolicy2;

        HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(NetFwPolicy2), 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pNetFwPolicy2));

        if (!FAILED(hr))
        {
            hr = pNetFwPolicy2->EnableRuleGroup(NET_FW_PROFILE2_ALL, group, enable);

            pNetFwPolicy2->Release();
        }
        SysFreeString(group);
        return hr;
    }
    else return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
}

EnableFirewallRule(L"@FirewallAPI.dll,-28752", VARIANT_TRUE);
```

---

yes, this not documented properly. however can found some info about this.

are radio button (*Allow remote connections to this computer*) selected depended only from `fDenyTSConnections` ( 0 or 1 (!= 0) ) - you can test it by changing value in regedit and reopen `System Properties/Remote` dialog

some proof on the MSND - [Using Remote Desktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd184089.aspx)

> A value of 0 for the **fDenyTSConnections** registry value means that
>   Remote Desktop is enabled on the system, while a value of 1 means that
>   Remote Desktop is disabled. If you later decide you want to disable
>   Remote Desktop on your Server Core installation, type cscript
>   %windir%\system32\scregedit.wsf /ar 1 at a command prompt.

**`UserAuthentication`** - [0 or 1 ] control *Network Level Authentication* checkbox (1 checked, 0 - unchecked) (again you can changing value in regedit and reopen `System Properties/Remote` dialog - or check/uncheck this this box and view in regedit)

> In the Properties pane, click the box to the right of the
>   **UserAuthentication** setting and type 1 to require Network Level Authentication, as shown here.

**SecurityLayer** - [0 or 1 or 2] - look the [Table 6-1 The SecurityLayer Setting Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd184089.aspx)

and the last for firewall (this is begin from vista)

> In the Properties pane, type C:\Windows\system32\netsh advfirewall
>   -firewall set rule group="Remote Desktop" new enable=yes

so we need enable rule group="Remote Desktop"

now look at this `technet.microsoft.com` [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749376(WS.10).aspx)

> For example, to enable Remote Desktop, use the following:
>   `<Group>@FirewallAPI.dll,-28752</Group>`

how is [Enabling a Group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd339607(v=vs.85).aspx) exist example on MSDN. my code snipet bassed on this

Comment: I think the line `if (BSTR group = SysAllocString())` should be `if (BSTR group = SysAllocString(group))` instead.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon - yes, of course. my error, when copy-paste ( initial was `BSTR group = SysAllocString(L"@FirewallAPI.dll,-28752")` ) . I fix code. thank you

Comment: This looks like opaque hackery that relies on implementation dependent details.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - yes, you right - I at begin look how system do this, and then search in google by unique strings/names. I update self answer - add some indirect proofs from msdn. unfortunately can not found better docs

Comment: You cannot proof a contract by looking at its implementation. Please do consider the possibility, that Stack Overflow is a resource for professionals, that need to know, whether something is guaranteed to work, or isn't. Hard to see, why this simple line of though doesn't appear to sink in with you.

Comment: @IInspectable - I provide some indirect links to documentation. if you can - provide better by self here